# mongodb,mongoose invalid database but works remotely

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, connection

I wanted to enable auth and remote acccess. 
for mongoose I use connect string: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database')`

It works if I connect remotely with compass, but mongoose.connect returns invalid database name.

However if i remove database name from the string, mongoose connects but to 'test' database and can't perform any action as it has no permissions (my user only have permission to certain database).

I really don't understand why is that happening.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the database name where username is stored

For example if user is in `database`

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?authSource=database')
```

If user is in admin database:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?authSource=admin')
```